# Validating variables in the state used in render() to style/populate html

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following React Component, which holds a form with two inputs and a button.

```
export default class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            email: null,
            password: null
        }
    }

    emailInputChanged = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            email: e.target.value.trim()
        });
    };
    passwordInputChanged = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            password: e.target.value.trim()
        });
    };

    loginButtonClicked = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (!this.isFormValid()) {
            //Perform some API request to validate data
        }
    };

    signupButtonClicked = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.history.push('/signup');
    };

    forgotPasswordButtonClicked = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.history.push('/forgot-password');
    };


    isFormValid = () => {
        const {email, password} = this.state;
        if (email === null || password === null) {
            return false;
        }

        return isValidEmail(email) && password.length > 0;
    };

    render() {
        const {email, password} = this.state;
        return (
            <div id="login">
                <h1 className="title">Login</h1>
                <form action="">
                    <div className={(!isValidEmail(email) ? 'has-error' : '') + ' input-holder'}>
                        <Label htmlFor={'loginEmail'} hidden={email !== null && email.length > 0}>email</Label>
                        <input type="text" className="input" id="loginEmail" value={email !== null ? email : ''}
                               onChange={this.emailInputChanged}/>
                    </div>
                    <div className={(password !== null && password.length === 0 ? 'has-error' : '') + ' input-holder'}>
                        <Label htmlFor={'loginPassword'}
                               hidden={password !== null && password.length > 0}>password</Label>
                        <input type="password" className="input" id="loginPassword"
                               value={password !== null ? password : ''}
                               onChange={this.passwordInputChanged}/>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default" id="loginButton"
                            onClick={this.loginButtonClicked}>
                        login
                    </button>
                </form>
                <div className="utilities">
                    <a href={'/signup'} onClick={this.signupButtonClicked}>don't have an account?</a>
                    <a href={'/forgot-password'} onClick={this.forgotPasswordButtonClicked}>forgot your password?</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export function isValidEmail(email) {
    const expression = /\S+@\S+/;
    return expression.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}
```

The values of the inputs are stored in the component's `state`. I have given them initial value of `null` and update them using `setState()` in the `onChange` event.

In the `render()` method I use the state to colour inputs with invalid values. Currently I am only checking the email value against a simple regex and the password to be at least 1 character in length.

The reason I have set the initial values of the state variables to `null` so I can check in the layout and the initial style on the input to not be marked as `"has-errors"`. However I need to extend the check to:

```
this.state.email !== null && this.state.email.length === 0
```

in order to work, because null has no `length` property.

Is there a cleaner and "React-ish" way to achieve this:
 - initial state of the div holding the inputs has no class `has-errors`
 - less checks when setting the `value` attribute on the input (because React doesn't accept `null` as value of the attribute)

---

*Edit:*
If the initial value of `this.state.email` and `this.state.password` are empty strings, I get `has-error` applied to the div holding the inputs. In my opinion this is bad UX, because the user hasn't done anything and he is *already wrong*.

The `hidden` attribute is used by a custom component I made, which acts like "placeholder" (gets erased if something is typed in the input).

Video below showing how my form looks like when `this.state.email` and `this.state.password` are empty strings as well how my `<Label>` component works:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could set the initial values to empty strings? I don't understand why you use null here.

Comment: I suggest to use Formik, it is a great library and provide nice and elegant places for error handling and validations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a validate function which return an errors object to know which fields are in error, and use empty strings as initial values. I don't understand what you are trying to do with the hidden attribute.

Edit: add a touched property in the state, to know which field have been touched.

```
export default class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      touched: {},
    };
  }

  emailInputChanged = e => {
    this.setState({
      email: e.target.value.trim(),
      touched: {
        ...this.state.touched,
        email: true,
      },
    });
  };

  passwordInputChanged = e => {
    this.setState({
      password: e.target.value.trim(),
      touched: {
        ...this.state.touched,
        password: true,
      },
    });
  };

  loginButtonClicked = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!this.isFormValid()) {
      //Perform some API request to validate data
    }
  };

  isFormValid = () => {
    const errors = this.validate();

    return Object.keys(errors).length === 0;
  };

  validate = () => {
    const errors = {};
    const { email, password } = this.state;

    if (!isValidEmail(email)) {
      errors.email = true;
    }

    if (password.length === 0) {
      errors.password = true;
    }

    return errors;
  };

  render() {
    const { email, password, touched } = this.state;
    const errors = this.validate();

    return (
      <div id="login">
        <h1 className="title">Login</h1>
        <form action="">
          <div
            className={
              (errors.email && touched.email ? 'has-error' : '') +
              ' input-holder'
            }
          >
            <Label htmlFor={'loginEmail'}>email</Label>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="input"
              id="loginEmail"
              value={email}
              onChange={this.emailInputChanged}
            />
          </div>
          <div
            className={
              (errors.password && touched.password ? 'has-error' : '') +
              ' input-holder'
            }
          >
            <Label htmlFor={'loginPassword'}>password</Label>
            <input
              type="password"
              className="input"
              id="loginPassword"
              value={password}
              onChange={this.passwordInputChanged}
            />
          </div>
          <button
            type="submit"
            className="btn btn-default"
            id="loginButton"
            onClick={this.loginButtonClicked}
          >
            login
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export function isValidEmail(email) {
  const expression = /\S+@\S+/;
  return expression.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}
```

Comment: This is a nice approach, thank you for sharing! I updated my question with example why I set the initial values of `this.state.email` and `this.state.password` to `null`. But I think if extend your suggestion of `validate()` function and keep the `null` values I can achieve what I am after.

Comment: I edited my answer and added a touched property in the state.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I implemented your approach and my app now looks really nice and clean (codewise).